# Gostaria de entender a utilização de um DTO com uma Entity

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software

Gostaria de saber se meu raciocínio está correto quanto a utilização de um DTO

Seguindo essa lógica, estou correto na utilização de um DTO?

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CadastroController
{
    private final CadastroRepository cadastroRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CadastroController(CadastroRepository cadastroRepository)
    {
        this.cadastroRepository = cadastroRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void save(final CadastroDTO cadastroDTO)
    {
        CadastroEntity cadastroEntity = new CadastroEntity();
        cadastroEntity.setNome(cadastroDTO.getNome());
        cadastroRepository.save(cadastroEntity);
    }
}
```

```java
public class CadastroDTO
{
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String nome;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cadastro")
public class CadastroEntity implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String nome;
}
```

Caso sim, devo utilizar o DTO apenas para armazenar as informações sem o risco de alteração das informações no banco de dados como aconteceria com uma entidade?

Comment: Você está utilizando o lombok, né?

Comment: Sim, uso lombok sim nos Getter Setter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A meu ver, a sua aplicação está correta.

Trafegar uma instância da `Entity` para fora do `Controller` não costuma ser boa ideia por permitir que se escreva código que tente alterá-la de forma inapropriada ou que acabe por fazendo isso em locais não previstos (por exemplo, ao acidentalmente disparar o carregamento de um *lazy load*), possivelmente após o commit ter sido feito ou ao forçar um escopo de transações não muito bem definido. Além disso, nem sempre o conteúdo de uma `Entity` vai ser o que a tela/funcionalidade em questão precisa, podendo ter informação de mais ou de menos, o que significa que haveria alguma violação do encapsulamento neste caso e a falta de uma camada de abstração.

Esses problemas acima, obviamente podem ser corrigidos ao programar-se todas essas coisas com o devido cuidado e atenção. Mas ao impôr essa restrição de não exportar a `Entity`, esses tipos de problemas referentes a transações e ao encapsulamento do `Entity`, em geral, desaparecem e o desenvolvimento da aplicação fica bem mais fácil e menos propenso a erros de programação.

Entretanto, alguma coisa tem que ser exportada para carregar os dados referentes a operação realizada, e para isso é que o DTO serve e você parece estar utilizando-o adequadamente. E é somente essa a finalidade do DTO, transportar dados de um lado a outro. Assim sendo, você transporta nele, aquilo que a operação em questão for utilizar.

Note que o DTO que você recebe no parâmetro do seu controller não precisa ser o mesmo que você retorna nele. O DTO do parâmetro contém os dados **recebidos** do navegador/usuário, enquanto que o DTO do retorno contém os dados a serem **enviados** ao navegador/usuário.

E obviamente, se for algo em que o navegador não precise informar nada, nenhum parâmetro é necessário. Se for algo onde apenas o fato de a resposta não ter sido uma exceção lançada for suficiente, um retorno `void` está bom.

No mais, parabéns pelo seu código. A meu ver está perfeito, não tenho o que criticar nele. Isso é muito raro de se ver aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Vitor, agradeço a resposta e o elogio. Sua resposta foi de grande ajuda no meu compreendimento.